# Kendo UI identify the caller for a datasource

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Hello and a Happy new year ya all!

My question might look kinda stupid, but I would really benefit from knowing which dom element (or ui element if you so choose) is calling for a specific data source. 

Let me exemplify. 

Let's say I have the following ui elements:
`<input data-ident="input1" data-bind="source: aFunction" type="text" />
 <input data-ident="input2" data-bind="source: aFunction" type="text" />`


Then, in the view controller I have this function:
`aFunction: function(propertyOf:uiElement){
      switch(propertyOf.data(ident)){
        case x:....
      }
      // return dataSource code...
}`

Is this doable in kendo? Can I read in the controller elements of the current ui element that gets its source from my function?
Many thanks and any help is much appreciated!